# Syntax error: Missing ; Before Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am getting a syntax error on seemingly fine code, also the error does not make sense so that indicates there is some foul play. However, I cannot seem to pinpoint it. On the first line, "`aoColumns: [`" it states that there is a missing semi-colon before statement. Here is the code in question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
"aoColumns": [
      { "sTitle": "", "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass":   "head0", "sWidth": "55px",
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
          if (data.IsDirectory) {
            return "<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
          } else {
            return "<a href='/" + data.Path + "' target='_blank'><i class='fa " + getFileIcon(data.Ext) + "'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
          }
        }
      }
    ]
"fnCreatedRow":  function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
      if (!aData.IsDirectory) return;
      var path = aData.Path;
      $(nRow).bind("click", function(e){
         $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
          table.fnClearTable();
          table.fnAddData(data);
          currentPath = path;
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Often caused by a spurious rabbits ear, brace, bracket or mismatched parentheses.

Comment: `"aoColumns": [` is a syntax error if it's not inside an object initializer.

Comment: are you using a library?

Comment: `"string" : value` can only be used in objects, so either change it into `var aoColumns = []` or wrap an object around your code.

Comment: @JDB: Not really. There are functions, string concatenation...

Comment: Looks like "aoColumns" doesn't end with ";"

Comment: What do you intend `"aoColumns": [` to mean? Is `aoColumns` supposed to be a variable? In which case you want `var aoColumns = [...`. Or is the whole thing supposed to be an object? In which case you want `var myObject = { "aoColumns": ... }`

Comment: @SamFen if it's going to be an object, there's still `,` missing before `"fnCreatedRow"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have looks like the *content* of an object initializer, but without the beginning and end of one. For instance, this is valid:

```
var object = {
"aoColumns": [
      { "sTitle": "", "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass":   "head0", "sWidth": "55px",
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
          if (data.IsDirectory) {
            return "<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
          } else {
            return "<a href='/" + data.Path + "' target='_blank'><i class='fa " + getFileIcon(data.Ext) + "'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
          }
        }
      }
    ],
"fnCreatedRow":  function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
      if (!aData.IsDirectory) return;
      var path = aData.Path;
      $(nRow).bind("click", function(e){
         $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
          table.fnClearTable();
          table.fnAddData(data);
          currentPath = path;
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
};
```

The changes are:

- Adding the `var object = {` at the top
- Removing the `;` from the `};` that used to be at the end, making it just `}`
- Adding a `};` to close the object
- Adding a `,` after the closing `]` on the `aoColumns` array

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    "key": value
};
```

Where are your curly braces? You're just trying to define object keys without placing them on an object, so that is why you're getting the syntax error.

```
var my_object = {
    "aoColumns": [
        // code here
    ],
    "fnCreatedRow":  function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        // function definition here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is not valid JavaScript syntax.

Assuming you want to **assign an array to variable `aoColumns`**, do the following:

```
var aoColumns = [
  { "sTitle": "", "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass":   "head0", "sWidth": "55px",
    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
      if (data.IsDirectory) {
        return "<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
      } else {
        return "<a href='/" + data.Path + "' target='_blank'><i class='fa " + getFileIcon(data.Ext) + "'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Same thing for `fnCreatedRow`.

If you are trying to **create a JavaScript object** with the two elements mentioned above instead, take a look at the other answers.